# Can Account Team member with ReadOnly Account Access be made Account Owner

Tags: account-teams

I have created an Account Team member with readonly Account access. When I login as the team member I am able to change the account owner however as expected I am not able to edit the the other fields or add New Team member. Is this the expected behaviour?

Note - I have given the profile of this member Transfer Record Permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account team member is able to change the owner because of the **Transfer Record Permission.** This is the expected behaviour.